# Hyper-V: guest OS requires internet driver

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, hyper-v, adapter

I'm using windows 10 64-bit on my Asus gl552jx-xo093d (i5-4200H). I just installed Windows 7 Starter (32-bit) as VM on Hyper-V. When I start the VM, I can't access the internet.
[image]
The problem is I can't install driver on the OS, I have tried: realtek, Intel, dell, but none working. I don't know what to do next. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank God, finally it works. Here how:

Step 1: Turn Off your (virtual machine) VM if you open it. Cause if you open your VM, you can't add Legacy

Step 2: Go to your VM's settings, like the picture below
[image: Choose settings]

Step 3: Choose Add Hardware, then Legacy Network Adapter, then add. Like the picture below
[image: Legacy Network Adapter]

Step 4: Set virtual switch for your Legacy Network Adapter.
[image: virtual switch Legacy Network Adapter]

Step 5: Open your VM and enjoy the internet
[image: Success]
Done! hope you enjoy :)